# Best way to remove useless features (non-english words) when there are more than 100,000 features?

Tags: neural-network, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am in a situation where i have more than 100,000 features, and i need to select the top features to give them to my final neural network model.

So far i have been using RandomForestClassifier in sklearn, and first i use fit and then i use feature_importances to select the top n features. ( I also use StandardScaler and transform to normalize data)

now i have two questions:

1. am i approaching this right? is this a correct way remove useless features?
2. is there any better way to select for example top 200 features to give to my final model when there are more than 100,000 features? my task is sentence classification and these features are actually BOW features of non english words, so basically i want to learn the top most important "words" in my corpus that can be used to classify sentences.

my final model is a neural network, but i cannot give all the features to it and let it decide because of performance issues, i need to filter some of the features and then give them to my neural network model. also my final model is written in pytorch, so currently i am using sklearn to select top n features and then use pytorch to train the final mode, so if there is an easier approach for this please let me know.

Comment: Did you search for "document embeddings"? You might also check https://paperswithcode.com/task/sentence-classification

Comment: @Graph4MeConsultant yes but i first wanted to try out the simple BOW approach, then compare the result to other complicated embedding approaches to see if there is any big difference. but there are a lot of unique words in this "language" i am working on, and i need to find the top important ones before training my final NN model

Comment: There are several concepts to approach this, which fall all under the term "feature selection" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection)

Comment: I found a survey which is public accessable: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3136625

Comment: In case you have access to the IEEE, there is a paper called "Sentiment Classification: Feature Selection Based Approaches Versus Deep Learning", which might be interesting to look at.

Comment: Regularization would be the best way (In my opinion) It might be using the 100K features (words vocabulary) and using a penalized model with lasso or other methods to push the non-significant variables to 0 or restricting the max number of features in the BoW matrix so that you only consider words that appear at least k times through documents (Recall also removing stopwords can reduce the size of the bow matrix)

Comment: @JulioJesusLuna so is there any big drawback of using a forest to choose the top n important features vs doing what you suggested?

Comment: Because one big problem of using 100k features is performance reasons, if we implement this it would be much better to use only for example 1000 features from sentences vs 100k in real world implementation.

Comment: As listed on the wikipedia articel, using lasso is one option. Using decision trees is another option..

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Regularized_trees

Comment: As per my second point, I suggest making the regularization while constructing the BoW matrix (before training a model), i.e keeping a limited number of features based upon their presence across documents. If you want to use Random forest, you can directly select the top N features based on RF importance. In case you are using python, this can be done with sklearn.feature_selection SelectfomModel https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html

Comment: @JulioJesusLuna  What is the difference between using the SelectFromModel vs just using fit on my classifier and then using feature_importances_?

Comment: There is no difference but the number of steps, with SelectfromModel everything is done with one line of code, in the second you first fit, then select and keep desired features based upon a threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have text data, you can remove frequently occurring words. This is typically done through sorting by tf-idf score. Frequently occurring words often have less signal than rare words.